# Node.js and Jquery passing variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, pug

I have a Node.JS Express application using Jade. I know how to send data from the backed to the front end using data.render({}). However, I cannot seem to give my jquery file js/script.js to get access to it. How can I pass in data to a front end js file?

Comment: thanks for point me to that

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer

```
script(type='text/javascript')  
var frontEndData = !{JSON.stringify(backEndData)}
```